# How login to my Facebook account when I am not sure of email, phone or password?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-account

[image]

I can not login to my account that has my image. Unfortunately, I am not sure about the email or phone I used when creating the account. I tried every email and phone I remember but it did not work. I tried “Forgotten Password” link, and it said it would send me a code to an email which I do not recognize(90% sure it’s not mine) to reset my password. And there is no other options, for example, sending code to my phone.

[image]

I tried clicking “ No longer have access to these?” link then in the next page, I clicked “ I can not access these accounts” link. it asked for a new primary email to connect to the account, then it took me to steps where I uploaded my national id card. But, unfortunately, it told me that it will send me an email(to the email that I do not recognize) to tell me that the national id was accepted or not. I assume my account was hacked. What can I do to get it back? Is there a way to contact Facebook for that?